# I would like to create a report that selects all users who have not logged in for 30 days

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I would like to create a report that selects all users who have not logged in for 30 days

I have setup a view that shows the USER_ID and then used a plugin to match the user to a username externally.

I see that there is a dimension in the user explorer called "last seen on" but I am not sure how to push to dataLayer and then create a report / alert.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the custom report in google datastudio.